# How to call a method with argument from HTM page and get a return string in Apache Click framework

Tags: java, click-framework

I have a page which is being extended to other pages in the UI. I have written a method which accepts and returns a String. I need to pass this string from HTM pages. I tried using `#getTextFromKey("xyz")` in HTM with having the same method in my common page being extended but it does not work.

Can anyone please help how to call a method in Java class from HTM page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass arguments to methods of `Page` class, but you can do an AJAX request to get similar behavior on the `load` event in the page.